# Question about Java code convert to Kotlin related to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin, firebaseui

I am writing Chatroom App and now I want to convert runnable Android Java code to Kotlin code. I try to assign `parser` as Null Safety by adding "?". However, I cannot compile the code.

Java version:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> parser = new SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>() {
    @Override
    public FriendlyMessage parseSnapshot(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        FriendlyMessage friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage.class);
        if (friendlyMessage != null) {
            friendlyMessage.setId(dataSnapshot.getKey());
        }
        return friendlyMessage;
    }
};
```

Kotlin version:

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val parser = object : SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage> {
    override fun parseSnapshot(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot): FriendlyMessage {
        val friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage::class.java)
        friendlyMessage?.setId(dataSnapshot.key!!)
        return friendlyMessage
    }
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
Type mismatch: inferred type is FriendlyMessage? but FriendlyMessage was expected


Required: friendlyMessage
Found: friendlyMessage?
```

Comment: You're returning a nullable `FriendlyMessage` (i.e. `FriendlyMessage?`) but the function is declared as returning a non-nullable `FriendlyMessage`. So you either force the return value to non-null, or you change the return value of `parseSnapshot` to `FriendlyMessage?`.

Comment: @m0skit0 I tried 1st one and get the same error message,  2nd doesn't work too as Andriod Studio returns this error `Return type of 'parseSnapshot' is not a subtype of the return type of the overridden member '@NonNull public abstract fun parseSnapshot(@NonNull p0: DataSnapshot): FriendlyMessage defined in com.firebase.ui.database.SnapshotParser'`

Comment: Sorry but if you force it to be not null, i.e. `return friendlyMessage!!`, there's no way it is the same error message. However this means you will get an NPE if it is ever null.

Comment: I can compile the code `return friendlyMessage!!` since `parseSnapshort` is `@nonnull`.

Answer (score 0):

The parser object is specified as

```
val parser = object : SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage>
```

Here the `FriendlyMessage` is non nullable and the overriden function `parseSnapshot` also has the same type `FriendlyMessage`. There are 2 ways to fix the error. The returned object can be changed to non null like this

```
return friendlyMessage!!
```

Please note that using !! is not recommended as it generates extra code for null checking and throwing an exception in case of null.

The second solution would be specifying the type as nullable.

```
mFirebaseDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference
val parser = object : SnapshotParser<FriendlyMessage?> {
    override fun parseSnapshot(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot): FriendlyMessage? {
        val friendlyMessage = dataSnapshot.getValue(FriendlyMessage::class.java)
        friendlyMessage?.setId(dataSnapshot.key!!)
        return friendlyMessage
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this already, but it failed because I get the same error message `Type mismatch: inferred type is FriendlyMessage? but FriendlyMessage was expected`